# abstract class in java-run time polymorphism-superclass reference

Tags: java, abstract-class, extends

I am getting an error while running below code

```
abstract class A {
    abstract void callMe();

    void callMeToo() {
        System.out.println("this is concrete method");
    }

}

class B extends A {
    void callMe() {
        System.out.println("B's implementation of callme");
    }
}

class AbstractDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        B b = new B();
        b.callMe();
        b.callMeToo();

    }
}
```

I got an error message like this below:

> run:
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: B
>       at abstractdemo.main(abstractdemo.java:28)
>   C:\Users\JARVIS\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\10.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\JARVIS\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\10.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: This compiles and runs fine for me. How are you running it?

Comment: The polymorphism is useless if you don't make b A type. If you make it B, it's practically the same as if you didn't have the A object.

Comment: The codes compiles and runs fine when using an IDE. My guess is that you are using command prompt to run this code and above source code lies in different `.java` files. If this is the case, compile file with `class A` first, then `class B` and then `class abstractdemo`

Comment: code runs fine, @AshishKumar is correctly said please provide more about the exception.

Comment: Follow the Java Standard for Naming Conventions for ClassName and methodName

Comment: NO i did not use command prompt to run this code. i am  just using netbeans  IDE.it shows duplicate class:A  and duplicate class : B in the adjacent side of the class A and B.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class AbstractDemo {
        abstract static class A { 
        public abstract void callMe(); 
        public void callMeToo() { }
      } 
      public static class B extends A { 
          public void callMe() { } 
      }
      public static void main(String args[]) {

        B b = new B();
        b.callMe();
        b.callMeToo();

     }
}
```

Comment: At line no 9[B b=new B()] : non static variable this cannot referenced from static context

Comment: Changed the classes to static for you